# What is the default MySQL database name in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I installed XAMPP, it came with a database, but I can't figure out where to find the name of it so I can connect to it... How can I find the name of my database?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html

Comment: `show databases` shows me a list of schemas; are schemas the same as databases in MySQL?

Comment: Yes, the command shows you the databases that's available in your db engine (innoDB or MyISAM).